# Is there a way to introduce punctuation into an italian sentence with python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech

as the title suggests, I need an API to introduce punctuation into an italian sentence.

I'm using SpeechRecognition to convert speech into text but the code that I implemented, gives me as output the sentence without punctuation.

My code is the following:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

recognizer_instance = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    recognizer_instance.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print("I'm listening... say something!")
    audio = recognizer_instance.listen(source)
    print("Ok! I'm processing the message!")
try:
    text = recognizer_instance.recognize_google(audio, language="it-IT")
    print("Google understood: \n", text)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

If I say, during the execution, this sentence:

> "Mi chiamo Paolo. Tu?"

which means "My name is Paolo. Yours?"

The output will be the following:

> I'm listening... say something!
>   Ok! I'm processing the message!
>   Google understood: 
>   mi chiamo Paolo tu

which does not take into account the punctuation.
How can I insert this information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Google Speech Recognition API supports punctuation for Italian, but you need to set `enable_automatic_punctuation=True` in the recognition config (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/automatic-punctuation#speech_transcribe_auto_punctuation-python)). A pull request adding this feature to the SpeechRecognition library is [currently open on GitHub](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/pull/432/commits/5833a057e38a9a3885b5cc4303c553e115f035b9). For now you can use the Google API directly or try to add punctuation as a post-processing step (seems like a lot of effort as it would most likely require training a model similar to [Punctuator](https://github.com/ottokart/punctuator2)).